# Intel XDK - Lock screen orientation

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I want to lock screen orientation to portrait on my Standard HTML5 app, made in Intel XDK. Cordova has a plugin for this, but can it be done in a Standard HTML5 project?

All I have found is this, but it seems that intel.xdk.device is retired and don't work anymore:

```
intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('portrait');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rasmus -- the orientation API you are referencing (`intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation`) has been retired. There is a standard Cordova plugin you should use, instead. However, you need to convert your standard HTML5 project to a Cordova project and make sure to add a reference to `cordova.js` in your index.html. Generally, it's easier to:

- start with a new blank "HTML5+Cordova" template
- copy your source files into that new project
- add the core Cordova "screen orientation" plugin

Select the "documentation link" on the plugin management page for that plugin to find the API docs for the plugin. That is, when you are viewing the description of that plugin, in the XDK plugin manager, click the "documentation" link to get to the description of that plugin's API.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to convert to Cordova project as you say. Btw, do you know if the orientation setting in Intel XDK works (as I talked about in above comments)?

Comment: The `intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation` API will only work if you include the corresponding plugin. It's not built into the standard webviews on the devices. The XDK creates a standard Cordova app, there is not secret sauce being added, it's mostly an easy front-end for creating Cordova apps. The plugin has gotten quite old (it's been retired), so you're better off using the core Cordova plugin I referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to you config.xml

```
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

You can read about the cordova config for XDK [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't seem to have a config.xml file. Are you sure this works with a Standard HTML5 project? I tried to put it in the intelxdk.config.additions.xml with no success.

Comment: If you use XDK and Cordova, you have a config.xml. Cordova needs a config.xml to build the app.

Comment: Ok, but I don't use Cordova. Only Standard HTML5, which is a common option in XDK. I guess there's not that option in that project type?

Comment: I changed the orientation to Portrait inside Intel XDK in Project > Build settings. However, it's still not working in app preview. Do you know if it will work after published to the stores?

Comment: Did you create a intelxdk.config.<platform>.xml file and add that to this file ? I don't have XDK in front of me so not sure about that build settings

Comment: No, the files was already there and I tried to add your code to it without success. However, when I changed the setting it added that code to the file automatically, so hopefully it will work in the stores.

Comment: Yes that should wok then. Best is always to test on a dev device and not too much with emulators. Good luck and if this helped, please upvote and validate!